# Do barbarian camps ever stop spawning?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I'm in a particularly long game, and I've been plagued by barbarians for the majority of it. I've since posted numerous units to remove a lot of the fog of war, but I haven't seen any camps for a long time (I have the honor social policy, so it notifies me).

Did they stop spawning due to the almost non-existent fog of war, due to the number of camps uncleared on the map, or because it is 2058 AD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They stop spawning due to fog of war being removed. They can spawn at any point in time if there is significant fog remaining. They also appear to refuse to spawn within a specific distance of another camp.